# I need a PL/SQL statement where it can concatenate list of individual rows to the string based on the number of rows. EX: for each 5 rows to 1 string

Tags: sql, plsql, group-by, listagg, rownum

**My select statement returns **

```
ID1
ID2
ID3
ID4
ID5
ID6
ID7
```

.
.
.
and so on
**My Output should be**

```
ID1,ID2
ID3,ID4
ID4,ID5
ID5,ID6
ID7
```

.
.
.
I have tried Group BY , List agg and rownum functions but it did not work. I use a SQL servlet with readonly access.

Answer (score 2):

To group successive rows, use `CEIL(id/2)`:

```
with cte as (
  select col1, CEIL(row_number() over (order by col1)/2) as grp
  from mytable
)
select LISTAGG(col1, ',')
from cte
group by grp
order by grp
```

Result :

| LIST |
| --- |
| ID1,ID2 |
| ID3,ID4 |
| ID5,ID6 |
| ID7 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/46uvYeDv)

Comment: A good approach. I would prefer `CEIL` over `ROUND`, though, because it leaves no doubt whether 2.5 gets rounded up (commercial rounding) or down (bankers' rounding).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks fro the remark, But I think `CEIL` and `ROUND` giving same result with positive numbers, only getting difference when dealing with negative numbers. I'm I wrong ?

Comment: Yep, they result in the same positive number. I just think that while it is obvious what `CEIL` does (round up), it may not be immediately obvious to all readers what `ROUND` does.